# CSS custom property change on inherited (color) value doesn't work

Tags: css, css-variables

I have this example below where `.bar` is inheriting `color: var(--color);` from it's parent.

If I then redefine `--color` to another color in `.bar`, the custom property doesn't update.

Can someone explain why, and what's needed to be able to change the value of `--color` in children that inherit that custom property?

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
  --color2: blue;
}

.foo {
  color: var(--color);
}

.bar {
  --color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  foo
  <div class="bar">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is properly redefined, but until you don't set the `color` property then the element `.bar` inherits the color from its parent, and in the scope of the parent that color is red.

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
  --color2: blue;
}

.foo {
  color: var(--color);
}

.bar {
  --color: var(--color2);
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  foo
  <div class="bar">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this doesn't work? I'm assuming it's by design, but I would expect the variable change to be reflected in the child's color by redefining the variable's value. It's funny, in Safari, if you inspect `.bar`, and then scroll to `.foo` in the dev tools, the var `--color` returns `blue`.

Comment: Please read again the explanation. You are _redefining_ the variable but you are not _using_ it

Comment: @MichaelCoker you should think CSS and not C++ .. you have a cascade, the variable is already evaluated at an upper level and it won't be evaluted again ...read the duplicate and you get more details example and the relevant part of the spec